# Spark can not serialize functional interface

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization, kryo, apache-spark-2.0

*Could you pls help me figure out why Spark fails yo serialize my functional interface `SerializablePredicate`?*

### Code that cause exception

```
public class NonSparkService {

    public void filter() {
        SerializablePredicate<MyClass> filter = new SerializablePredicate<Pair>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Pair pair) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        new SparkFilterJob().run(filter);
    } 
}

public class SparkFilteringJob implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SparkFilteringJob.class);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 43L;

    public void run(SerializablePredicate filter) {

        sparkConf configuration =
            new SparkConf()
                .setAppName(name)
                .setMaster(host)
                .setJars(jars)
                .set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")
                .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
                .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "10") 
                .set("spark.executor.cores", "7")
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "7GB") 
                .set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
                .set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "1024m")
                .set("spark.rpc.askTimeout", "500s")
                .set("spark.rpc.lookupTimeout", "500s")
                .set("spark.rpc.numRetries", "10")
                .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
               .set("spark.kryo.registrator", "my_package_path.MyKryoRegistrator")

        return SparkSession
                .builder()
                .config(configuration)
                .getOrCreate()
                .read()
                .parquet(pathStr)
                .as(Encoders.kryo(MyClass.class)) // MyClass implements Serializable

                //Problem - this filter cause java.io.NotSerializableException, but I can serialize SerializablePredicate (see code below)
                .filter(new FilterFunction<MyClass>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean call(MyClass value) throws Exception {
                        return filter.test(value);
                    }
                })
                .collectAsList();
      }
}
```

### MyKryoRegistrator.java

```
public class MyKryoRegistrator implements KryoRegistrator {

    @Override
    public void registerClasses(Kryo kryo) {
        kryo.register(SerializablePredicate.class);
    }
}
```

### SerializablePredicate

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SerializablePredicate<T> extends Predicate<T>, Serializable {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}. The result is serializable if {@code other} is.
     */
    default SerializablePredicate<T> and(SerializablePredicate<T> other) {
        return (SerializablePredicate<T>) value -> test(value) && other.test(value);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}. The result is serializable if {@code other} is.
     */
    default SerializablePredicate<T> or(SerializablePredicate<T> other) {
        return (SerializablePredicate<T>) value -> test(value) || other.test(value);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}. The result is serializable.
     */
    default SerializablePredicate<T> negate() {
        return (SerializablePredicate<T>) value -> !test(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your predicate has reference to your class, in this case it's the class with code from first snippet

Comment: @T.Gawęda could you pls explain in more details?

Comment: Please post whole class from first snippet, then I will be able to comment what is causing this problem

Comment: @T.Gawęda sorry, there are a lot of not-spark related code there. Could you pls tell in which code you are interested? Could you pls explain your first statement?

Comment: @T.Gawęda here is my class, as you asked

Comment: @T.Gawęda finally it works for me! That happens that I created `SerializablePredicate` from non-serializable class. Thanks for your tip!! Could you pls explain why this happens and how it works?